# Automata that is Turing complete if you add a nondeterminism

Tags: automata, computation-models, nondeterminism, turing-completeness

Pushdown automata have an interesting property: non-deterministic ones belong to a different computational class than deterministic ones. This is in contrast to finite state and turing machines, for which adding nondeterminism does not change the computational class.

Is there a class of automata that is not Turing complete, but becomes Turing complete if you add nondeterminism?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean that it is in contrast to Turing machines; P vs NP is still open last I checked.

Comment: @PålGD The question seems to be about *computation* theory (i.e., Turing-completeness), not *complexity* theory.

Comment: @PålGD dkaeae is correct. Deterministic turing machines can simulate nondeterministic ones.

Comment: So when you say _computational class_, you mean the position in the arithmetical hierarchy?  I was not aware of that terminology.

Comment: @PålGD Computational class is slightly more fine grained. Also, your edit had some errors. Nondeterministic push down automata are still computable, but they belong to a higher class than deterministic push down automata.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by computational class. Can you either define it or provide a reference?

Comment: Nitpicking about the phrasing aside, I think the question is clear: Is there a computational model X with class of (non-)deterministically accepted languages (N)X, for which X ⊊ RE but NX = RE?

Comment: Well, it's not clear to me, I'm curious about the definition of computational classes which is more fine grained than the arithmetical hierarchy, but (?) less fine grained than the polynomial hierachy.

Comment: maybe related: nonemptiness of universal register automata is undecidable, but for deterministic (and non-det) register automata it is decidable. Register automata operate on letters from an infinite domain. It is an automaton equipped with a finite number of registers: you can save data-value into a register, then compare with it when deciding where to move; whether to save value into a register also depends only on the comparison, but not on exact values.